# How would I add noise to a voltage source in SystemModeler?

Tags: system-modeler

I have a simple circuit with a SawTooth voltage source in SystemModeler 12.0.

How would I add a noise component to a sawtooth waveform?

- I have added a NormalNoise block named normalNoise1 to my model.
- I can plot normalNoise1 in my output run.
- I would like to add normalNoise1.y to the amplitude of my SawTooth source.  In my case this would be `20 + normalNoise1.y`.
- When I tried using `20 + normalNoise1.y` as an expression for the amplitude entry of the SawTooth source, I get an error.

My two questions are:

- Is there a good reference for the syntax for the expression editor in SystemModeler?  I have looked for some examples that use expressions but am not finding anything.
- Is it even possible to use a noise block in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write `20 + normalNoise1.y` as the expression for the amplitude, since the amplitude is a parameter (something that you set once, and is constant during the whole simulation), and `normalNoise1.y` is a variable (changes during the simulation).

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. What does a sawtooth with a noisy amplitude  look like? If you want the sum of a regular sawtooth and some noise, you can achieve that using three components:

- Noise block (like you have)
- `Modelica.Blocks.Sources.SawTooth` block (with a set amplitude, like `20`)
- `Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add` to add the two together
- `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Sources.SignalVoltage` to get the signal into your circuit

Comment: I don't believe that the Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add will work with the voltage signal type. I think the only solution is to write a custom C++ function.

Comment: You can find a number of examples of noisy sawtooth waves in Google images and the ElectricalEngineering exchange.

Comment: I edited my answer for how you could get a sawtooth signal into an electric circuit.